70's TV movie involving abandoned desert Christmas town
Trying to remember a TV movie I saw as a kid in the early to mid 1970's, which I'm pretty sure was a drama and/or thriller. If I remember right, it involved a couple that was running from someone and got stuck in a town in middle of the desert that was a sad, derelict Christmas themed little town, that appeared to have been designed to get folks to come visit but had failed. I remember the show's theme being a bit dark (at least to a youngster in the early to mid seventies) and the sad "failed-ness" of the little town added to the atmosphere. 
In one scene I kind of remember faded, paint-peeling Santa Claus and Christmas tree signs as the camera panned by. The protagonists were there in daytime. I'm guessing the set was supposed to invoke or imitate Santa Claus, Arizona, which was probably in the news around about then, prompting the screenwriter to steal the idea for his movie. I've looked at Google images of the real Santa Claus AZ, and I don't believe it was filmed there. 
It was an American made for TV film, if I remember the actors were all Caucasian. It was a color movie, too. I was pretty young, perhaps it was a theatrical released film that was being shown as a 'Movie of the Week', but I think it was made for television.
Not much to go on, I know. But if it rings a bell, let me know!

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the genre, language, country and year of production, descriptions of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

It was an American made for TV film, if I remember the actors were all Caucasian. It was  a color movie, too. I was pretty young, perhaps it was a theatrical released film that was being shown as a 'Movie of the Week', but I think it was made for television. If I remember any further details, I'll post, but that's all I can think of right now.
